# anyone going to NNg conference in San Fancisco?

Tags: discussion, conference

http://www.nngroup.com/events/san_francisco/agenda.html

I'm attending mobile user experience thu/fri

anyone else going? Can pop a few business cards to folks if not....

Comment: CHAOS team here - we can get some stickers / SE lanyards / other swag out to you @colmcq, if you are interested. Let me know and I will get in touch re: shipping.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like a plan. email colin///removespam///@liquidthinking.co.uk

Comment: Anyone else going to the conference?

Comment: hows the Glasgow accent going?

Comment: @katey W I got the stuff, thanks!

Comment: Remember to [leave some feedback](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/15128/feedback-on-nielsen-norman-groups-usability-week-2012)!

Answer (score 3):

conference:

I attended mobile user experience 1 and 2 on Sept 29 and 30.

My expectations: to learn detailed mobile design guidelines and what academic research backed up those guidelines; psychological principles of mobile UX.

Verdict:
While I learned some interesting new things, my general impression was that this was a very basic course, surprisingly so. The first seminar tended to veer into general usability which was incredibly frustrating and not appropriate. The second day was better but still covered common UX themes.

Who should attend this course:
non UX staff who would like to know basic UX principles for mobile design

Who should not attend this course:
Individuals with background and experience in UX

Incidental
I got chatting to a couple of blokes next to me and went out to lunch with them. Turns out one was @phil from the forum; he never visits meta.

Comment: I wonder what proportion of users *do* visit meta (ux or se generally). Anyone know?

Comment: i dont know; I did not for many months because i wasn't ware of the purpose or value. Still not tbh apart from 'informal chat' aspect.

Comment: Most meta sites aren't particularly active. We're always looking for suggestions on how to increase awareness and usability of the metas.

Comment: its not very prominent of the nav bar. Maybe try a different visual styling